# Power set proof

Tags: discrete-mathematics, elementary-set-theory

Hello again everyone,

i have a question about 2 problems in proofs , i did both of them but i think the first one is not considered a proof.
**The first** : **P(A\b)⊆ (P(A)\P(B))∪{∅}** , the way i did it was by saying that A={1,2} , B={2,3} so A\B={1} therefore P(A\B} = {∅,1} and (P(A)\P(B))∪{∅} is also {∅,1} .. but as far as i know this isn't a proof and they request a more formal one.
**The second** : **|P(A)|=|P(A∩B)|*|P(A\B)|** , the way i did it was i said A=n , and A∩B=m then A\B=n-m therefore 2^n = 2^m * 2^n-m is 2^n=2^n

i think the problem is with the first question as i believe my way isn't a formal way.

thank you! appreciate all the help

Comment: You are correct that your approach to the first is only exhibiting a single example of when the identity holds true and is not a proof that it is true for all possible examples.  Now, to actually try to prove the first, use an "*element-chasing*" argument.  Start by taking an arbitrary element of $P(A\setminus B)$ and showing that it follows by some chain of logic that the element will necessarily also be an element of $(P(A)\setminus P(B))\cup \{\emptyset\}$.

Comment: So, suppose that $X$ is an element of $P(A\setminus B)$.  If $X=\emptyset$ then clearly $X\in (P(A)\setminus P(B))\cup \{\emptyset\}$ and we are done, so suppose otherwise that $X$ is not empty.  Then $X$ must be a subset of $A\setminus B$... I leave the rest to you, but try to explain why it follows that $X$ will necessarily be a subset of $A$ and why it follows that $X$ is not a subset of $B$ and how it implies the final desired result.

Comment: Hello i am sorry for the many question as i am new to this topic of math.. i am still not able to prove it with "element chasing" i think that if X∈(P(A\B) then X∈A but X∉B therefore X⊆A\B or just X⊆A (im not sure) and for (P(A)∖P(B))∪{∅} if X∈ A and X∉B then for  (P(A)∖P(B))  its also X⊆A but i am stuck.. and unsure of my approaches

Comment: Here's a proof that all horses live in California.  My friend Stan has a horse ranch in Santa Barbara.  All his horses are in California.  So if it works for the horses on Stan's Ranch it must work for all horses.  .... A single example is not a proof.  Ever.

Comment: Bear in mind the elements of $P(...)$ are *sets*.  So if $x \in P(A\setminus B)$ then $x \subset A\setminus B$  So $x\subset A$ but $x$ contains no elements of $B$.  So unless $x = \emptyset$ then $x \not \subset B$.  So $x\in P(A)$ but unless $x$ is empty, then $x \not \in P(B)$.

Comment: thank you for the help!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Suppose that $X\in P(A\setminus B)$, in other words $X$ is an *element of* $P(A\setminus B)$.

That means that $X\subseteq (A\setminus B)$, in other words $X$ is a *subset of* $A\setminus B$.

Supposing further that $X\neq \emptyset$, that means that $X$ contains at least one element.

Since $X\subseteq (A\setminus B)$, that means that every element in $X$ is an element of $A\setminus B$.  In particular, this means that every element of $X$ is an element of $A$ and is not an element of $B$.  In particular, this implies that $X\subseteq A$ and $X\not\subseteq B$.

> (*No element of $X$ being an element of $B$ is a much stronger condition than $X\not\subseteq B$, but the observation we made is all we really needed for our purposes of proving the desired statement*)

$~$

> *Note here that if it were that $X=\emptyset$ this also satisfies the condition that every element (remembering that none exist) of $X$ is an element of $A$ and not an element of $B$.  To conclude that $X\not\subseteq B$ required that we assume that $X$ is nonempty, which we did earlier*

In particular then, that means that $X\in P(A)$ and $X\notin P(B)$.

Finally, this means that $X\in (P(A)\setminus P(B))$ and as a result $X\in (P(A)\setminus P(B))\cup\{\emptyset\}$

---

Each step above follows almost directly from definitions.  Pay careful attention to the distinction between "being an element of" and "being a subset of."  Pay attention to the definition of what it means to be an element of, what it means to be a subset of, and what the powerset of a set is.

Comment: Amazing thank you for the detailed explanation appreciate it a lot